# A list is a vector?

Tags: vectors

So I'm watching this video to learn about neural networks : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tMrbN67U9d4

At 9:07, the author says that in mathematics a list is a vector.

So for example, `[0, 1, 7, 3, 2, 6]` would be a vector.

I don't understand how. I thought that a vector was a set of derivatives coordinates, like dx:2 and dy:3 would be a 2d vector.

Would someone please explain **in simple terms** why a list can be considered a vector, and how it works ?

Thanks.

Comment: I would say that a list like yours, which has form $\{x_1,\dots,x_6\}$, can be very reasonably considered as a element of real vector space $R^6$, the "real 6-tuple space."

Comment: No reason to require derivatives in a vector space story.

Comment: Vectors can be very abstract things and don't need to conform to ideas such as "lists" or "tuples"... they merely need to be objects in a space that satisfy some requirements about adding vectors together results in another vector and there needs to be some way to "scale" the vectors larger or smaller and such using elements from a scalar field and so on...  That said, one of the most common examples of vectors first introduced are $n$-tuples of real numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's programmer jargon. When a programmer talks about a *vector* it's often the same as an [array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure) or a [tuple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple) where all elements are of the same type.

For example, C++ comes with a [vector class](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) with description: "Vectors are sequence containers representing arrays that can change in size."

Comment: On the contrary, I think "[list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_(abstract_data_type))" is a word that programmers are much more likely to say than mathematicians. I cannot think of any mathematical context where "list" is normally said instead of "vector" or "sequence".

Comment: @kaya3. That too. Lists are hardly used in mathematics.

Comment: @md2perpe why not use just one word instead of *vector*, *array*, *tuple*, *sequence* and *list* if they all mean pretty much the same thing?

Comment: @ᴍᴇʜᴏᴠ. In some programming languages, e.g. PHP, the same structure is used for them all. In other languages there are some differences. For example, in C++, all elements of an array or vector are of the same type, however array has a fixed size while vector can vary in size. A tuple has a fixed number of elements, possibly of different types.

Answer (score 2):

No need to think about derivatives, coordinates, or any of this extra stuff.

A vector is indeed just an *ordered list of variables*. That's all there is to it. $[1,2,3,4,5]$ is a perfectly good vector. As is $[x_1, x_2]$.

From there you can build all kinds of abstractions. For example, when you're looking at a cartesian grid, it's common to express $x$ and $y$ coordinates in a vector of form $[x,y]$.

If you want to be very formal and correct, a vector needs to belong to a vector space -- a set of vectors -- that satisfies some abstract requirements about adding vectors together, and about being able to multiply vectors by scalars. But that level of formality is not what you need at this level.

Comment: I would discourage the use of curly braces here as it may be confused with set notation.  Parentheses or square brackets would be preferred as curly braces might carry with it the connotation that order within the braces doesn't matter while parentheses and square brackets carry with it the connation that order within it does matter.  Of course, anything can be defined to mean anything you want, even if it contradicts with more standard definitions... but best to avoid the ambiguity

Comment: @JMoravitz yep fair call

Answer (score 2):

Consider $\mathbf{R}^n$. For example for $n=2$, you have $\mathbf{R}^2$. If $n>3$ then it can be complicated to visualize the space, but you can construct it.

Now, build what we call the canonical base $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$  where $e_1\dots e_n$ are vector of the form: $(1,0,\dots,0) \;\; \dots\;\; (0,0,\dots,1)$. Here, a general $n-$tuple of numbers represents a unique vector $v=(v_1,\dots,v_n)$.

Comment: I don't even know what $\mathbf{R}^n$ means, to me, $\mathbf{R}$ represents the real numbers. I didn't know you could add exponents to that.

Comment: @Loic: yeah, this can be helpful. Nevertheless, I will leave this answer, so that oders can read it. I suggest you to start leanring linear algebra because it's a foundamental branch of mathematics and ML or AI.

Comment: @Loïc. $\mathbf{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{R}^n$ denotes the set of $n$-tuples of real numbers. It's also a [vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space). The vectors that we usually learn about in physics (e.g. velocity and force) live in $\mathbb{R}^3.$